# Crear accesos temporales en laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde un tutor puede crear credenciales temporales para que los alumnos que tiene asignados puedan ingresar a realizar un test, la tabla test cuenta con los atributos:

`id, nick,password, status, student_id`

He leído que hay alguna forma sencilla de volverlo un modelo autenticable pero todo esta enfocado a la tabla user y no quiero tocar esa parte.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza softdeletes y podrás des-habilitar las cuentas cuando este campo tenga un timestamp que no sea  NULL.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: Muchas gracias alex, esa parte esta muy interesante, el problema es que no consigo volver el modelo test autenticable, creo que todos los metodos estan efocados a usar el modelo user, pero necesito ademas, hacerlo con este modelo test.

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes intentar hacer es una tabla profiles con relación 1-1 es bastante sencillo para cada perfil tienes un user, y poner un campo de habilitar des-habilitar con un booleano o algo así. 

Yo no toco la tabla User que trae por defecto el auth de laravel, lo que hago es crear tablas de uno a uno, tanto para profiles, como para social logins etc, pero nada directamente en la de user.

Comment: @AlexL.Rocha, te recomiendo mejorar tu respuesta, las respuestas que poseen enlaces no son del todo válidas en el sitio. Por favor lee: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AlexL.Rocha agregar mejoras a tu respuesta según comentarios en vez de responder en los comentarios evita que te mosquean con votos de eliminación. ;) Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Auth Block User.

Añade un nuevo campo a tu tabla usuarios llamado **'status'** de tipo boolean.

Luego en **app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php** escribe un nuevo método del tipo:

```
protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
  $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
  return array_add($credentials, 'status', '1');
}
```

Por último en el modelo no te olvides de añadir **->where('status', 1)** dónde recuperes tus usuarios.